# php Num rows of stored procedure MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a stored procedure in MySQL. I call my procedure in php as

```
$qry = $mysqli->prepare("CALL seen_table()");
```

i tried to get the resulting rows by

```
$row = $qry->num-rows;
```

but its resulting `0` even there is a resulting set.Then I tried also to put output parameter in my procedure where in inside of my proc is ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM TBL
```

...then this is my codes

```
 $qry = $mysqli->prepare("CALL seen_table(@cnt)");
 $qry1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT @cnt");
 $row = $qry1->num_rows;
```

then now its always results 1 even there is no count. when i try to execute `CALL` and `SELECT @cnt` in Mysql . if there is no count. the result will be

```
|@cnt|
|(null)|
```

does null really count as one?please help. thanks a lot.

EDIT: Added seen_table Procedure codes

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `xiroosco_mundoxiro`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `seen_table`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`xiroosco`@`103.16.170.%` PROCEDURE `seen_table`(bound
VARCHAR(255),IN cmntId INT,IN cmntViewID VARCHAR(255),OUT viewCNT INT) 
BEGIN 

DECLARE seen_ID INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE seen_notifica_ID INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE seen_viewers TEXT; 
DECLARE occurance INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE splitted_value INT; 
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT seen.seen_ID, seen.seen_notifica_ID,
seen.seen_viewers 
                FROM seen 
                WHERE seen.seen_notifica_ID = cmntId; 
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1; 

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS seen2; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE seen2( 
`seen_ID` INT NOT NULL, 
`seen_notifica_ID` INT NOT NULL, 
`seen_viewers` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=MEMORY; 

OPEN cur1; 
 read_loop: LOOP 
  FETCH cur1 INTO seen_ID,seen_notifica_ID, seen_viewers; 
  IF done THEN 
   LEAVE read_loop; 
  END IF; 

  SET occurance = (SELECT LENGTH(seen_viewers) -
LENGTH(REPLACE(seen_viewers, bound, '')) +1); 
  SET i=1; 
  WHILE i <= occurance DO 
   SET splitted_value = (SELECT
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(seen_viewers, bound, i), 
   LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(seen_viewers, bound, i - 1)) + 1), ',', '')); 

   INSERT INTO seen2 VALUES (seen_ID,seen_notifica_ID, splitted_value); 
   SET i = i + 1; 

  END WHILE; 
 END LOOP; 
 IF cmntViewID = "*" THEN 
  SELECT * FROM seen2 GROUP BY seen2.seen_viewers; 
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO viewCNT FROM seen2; 
 ELSE 
  SELECT * FROM seen2 WHERE seen2.seen_viewers = cmntViewID GROUP BY
seen2.seen_viewers; 
  SELECT seen_ID INTO viewCNT FROM seen2 WHERE seen2.seen_viewers =
cmntViewID GROUP BY seen2.seen_viewers; 
 END IF; 
CLOSE cur1; 
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

this is how i call my procedure example

```
CALL seen_table (',',2995,'356',@count);
```

Comment: In this case, yes. Have you tried using your procedure as a query in php? You also probably shouldn't use prepare, just query with your stored procedure.

Comment: hi, if i use query(call) its not working. i dont know why. if prepare it will work. it will work using query if its in procedural way not in OOP

Comment: Instead of doing what you're doing assign the count to something(`select @cnt as cnt`), fetch results, and then echo `$result->cnt`. You still may get 1. Are you certain your procedure is correct? Have you run it separately?

Comment: yes my procedure is correct i run it in mysql first before applying in my php.

Comment: @ElefantPhace is there any other way to get the count of $qry = $mysqli->prepare("CALL seen_table()"); . i will post my procedure codes wait

Answer (score 0):

NULL counts as one, but as far as I can see it is against the ANSI standard: If there are not results, there should also be no NULL returned.

To get a row count returned from a procedure (or any result set) in MySQL, there are information functions.

I do not know which select you want to return the count, so just giving you an example:

```
{your procedure before this part}
IF cmntViewID = "*" THEN 
  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM seen2 GROUP BY seen2.seen_viewers; 
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO viewCNT FROM seen2; 
 ELSE 
  SELECT * FROM seen2 WHERE seen2.seen_viewers = cmntViewID GROUP BY
seen2.seen_viewers; 
  SELECT seen_ID INTO viewCNT FROM seen2 WHERE seen2.seen_viewers =
cmntViewID GROUP BY seen2.seen_viewers; 
 END IF;
{your procedure after this part}
```

Then execute:

```
CALL seen_table();
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

That will return the number of rows in the "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM seen2 GROUP BY seen2.seen_viewers;" query.

Comment: (null) != null, in this case. "(null)" is the result of his query, which is one object that is null

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedures-return-multiple-values/. Also when asking a question about a stored procedure, show us the code inside that stored procedure.

Comment: my code for my procedure is too long. can i post it here?

Comment: i posted now my procedure codes. is there any other way i can get the number of rows for my  `$qry = $mysqli->prepare("CALL seen_table()");`